# how to make child process when it finishes to return immediately to run parent process ( when we do fork )?

Tags: c++, fork

i wrote a function that simulate cp function (copy in bash ) , basically this function takes a file as an input and copies it to a dest file :

```
cp sourceFile destFile .
```

the cp function can run in fore ground or in back ground if there was a '&' at the end of the line (`cp sourceFile destFile &` )

in order to support this i used fork , and the son basically copies the file , and he father if the command was fore ground waits for the child , else if the command is back ground we don't wait ( we add it to certain list )

my problem is when the command runs in fore ground after the son finishes the code exit the cp function then returns , but when it exits the cp function it prints something , and i don't want this to happen :(

( example at the end )

my function :

```
void CopyCommand::execute() {
    char *buff = new char[1024]();
    int fdRead = open(args[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fdRead == -1) {
        perror("smash error: open failed");
        return;
    }

    int fdWrite = open(args[2], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
    if (fdWrite ==-1) {              
        fdWrite = open(args[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
        if (fdWrite == -1) {
            perror("smash error: open failed");
            return;
        }
    }

    PID = fork();
    if (PID == 0) {
        setpgrp();
        int count = read(fdRead, buff, 1);  /// read from the file fd1 into fd2
        while (count != -1) {
            if (!count) {
                break;
            }
            if (write(fdWrite, buff, 1) == -1) {
                perror("smash error: write failed");
                return;  // not sure if we should return
            }
            count = read(fdRead, buff, 1);
            if (count == -1) {
                perror("smash error: read failed");
                return;
            }
        }
        return ;
    }  if (PID > 0) { // if i am the father then i will :
        if (isBackground) {
            // if cp command is running in the background then add it to the jobs list
            SmallShell::getInstance().SmallShellGetJobs()->removeFinishedJobs();
            SmallShell::getInstance().Jobs_List.addJob(SmallShell::getInstance().currentCommand, false);
            cout << "smash: " << args[1] << " was copied to " << args[2] << endl;
            return;
        } else {
            int status;
            waitpid(PID, &status, WUNTRACED);
            cout << "smash: " << args[1] << " was copied to " << args[2] << endl;
            return;
        }
    } else {
        perror("smash error: fork failed");
    }
}
```

what happens :
for example the input is :

```
 cp test_src_1.txt test_newdest_1.txt
```

the output would be :

```
outside of cp function :(
smash: test_src_1.txt was copied to test_newdest_1.txt
```

Comment: Note that this is the behavior when you add an `&` in bash (just try `echo test &`).

Comment: The shown code has a ghastly memory leak. Can you explain what you were hoping to accomplish by manually `new`ing a buffer instead of using `std::vector` to manage this allocation for you, correctly? Now you have to remember to always `delete` it. It seems that you never did, anywhere. Why did you decide to `new` the buffer, forcing yourself  to deal with the additional overhead of remembering it to `delete` it everywhere you `return` from this function, and you never did. Doesn't it seem to make much more sense to you to use `std::vector` and simply let it worry about doing all of this?

Comment: but i didn't put & at the end of the line test that i am testing

Comment: ok i am gonna change it to vector , but that is not my main problem now ! my problem is why after the son finishes copying the file it returns out of the function and prints something then returns to run the father process ??\

Comment: "parent/child", not "father/son"

Comment: ok ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork` doesn't work the way you think it does.  The child process exists until it's terminated, and inherits things like the parent's call stack; when you `return` in the child process, you're just going to the calling function.

You need to use `exit` or something in the same family.  For example:

```
if (PID == 0) {
        setpgrp();
        int count = read(fdRead, buff, 1);  /// read from the file fd1 into fd2
        while (count != -1) {
            if (!count) {
                break;
            }
            if (write(fdWrite, buff, 1) == -1) {
                perror("smash error: write failed");
                exit(0);  // not sure if we should return
            }
            count = read(fdRead, buff, 1);
            if (count == -1) {
                perror("smash error: read failed");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        exit(1) ;
    }
```

Comment: and exit basically ends the child process ? returns to the parent ? it actually worked i am so happy !!!!! thank you

Comment: `exit` terminates the current process.  Nothing "returns to the parent" since the parent process still runs on its own (although you're blocking with `waitpid`).

Comment: that was actually really helpful ! thank you :)